# Boot Camp creates a "Removable" Non-Reassignable "F" Drive in Windows 7. I need F reassigned

Tags: windows, boot-camp, partitioning

I desperately need an external drive I use for media (specifically mp3's for iTunes purposes) to bear the drive letter F as it does on my PC.
I've successfully installed Windows 7 via Bootcamp on my iMac running 10.6.7, but when I connect my external hard drive in Windows, it is assigned the letter G. I tried going in to Windows disk management to reassign its letter but am unable to as F is assigned to a "removable drive" on "Disk 2" and can't be changed. Here's a screenshot of how it looks in Windows disk management:

[image]

I have nothing else connected to the computer. I tried renaming the OS X partition from "E" to "Z" hoping that whatever's taking the "F" letter would be reassigned but nothing changed.

All I want is to have the drive letter "F" free so I can assign it to my external hard drive.

Comment: I'm having the same problem. It is solveable because I did it about 6 months ago with one installation, but today I'm experiencing the same problem. With XP you disable a file called AppleMNT.sys
see http://support.apple.com/kb/HT3841 I've tried it with my most recent install of Windows 7 and it did not work. If you figure it out, please post it .

Answer (score 1):

Okay, I just solved my same problem this morning. You are at the correct place, but right click on the Disk 1 (F drive) and select "Change Drive Letter and Paths". Don't do a rename, but rather it allows you to change it to a differnt letter such as 'Z'.
I succeeded with changing mine today.